Query and return aggregate from a jsonb column in postgresql 14+
Is there an efficient way to aggregate data from a jsonb column in postgresql?  Given the table
userdata(id STRING, data JSONB)
and the data
123.abc, { "dis": ["close"] }
123.abc, { "purpose": {"score": 0.1, "text": "hi"}, "dis": ["hello", "close"]}
123.abc, { "dis": ["bye"], "dir": 1}
123.abc, {}
567.bhy, { "dis", ["close"]}

I'm trying to get the following result:
123.abc, { "dis": ["close", "hello", "bye"], "purpose": {"score": 0.1, "text": "hi", "dir": 1} 
567.bhy, {"dis", ["close"]}

As you notice, I want unique values of keys (for e.g. "dis") across all records indexed by the id.
I tried getting values using jsonb_agg and jsonb_array_elements.  I could not aggregate all keys and distinct values. I couldn't figure out how to use jsonb_each to get all keys
What I tried is something like this to get one key.
select id,
       (select jsonb_agg(t->>'dis') from jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb) as x(t) where t->>'dis' is not null) as sdata
from mytable where id='123.abc'

Any help with the query is appreciated.

Do you ever have multiple purpose keys and if so what result would you want?

Putting it another way: how many keys do you have and how many of them are just bare arrays, and what do you want to do if a duplicate key exists as an object not an array?

purpose is a unique key. It won't be there in other records. There are other keys like purpose, that exist only once for a given id.  They could be in any of the records for that id.   Only dis, an array object, can be in more than one record.  The values of dis need to be merged to get distinct values.

You need to first shred each row into key/value pairs. Then (conditionally if it's the dis key) shred the value as an array.
Then re-aggregate on two levels, first for any possible dis array, then for all properties. The other properties you just need to take the first value in the aggregated array.
select
  t.id,
  jsonb_object_agg(t.key, case when t.key = 'dis' then t.value else t.value->0 end) as final_json
from (
    select
      mt.id,
      props.key,
      jsonb_agg(coalesce(j.dis, props.value)) as value
    from mytable as mt
    cross join jsonb_each(mt.t) as props
    left join jsonb_array_elements(case when props.key = 'dis' then props.value end) as j(dis) on 1=1
    group by
      mt.id,
      props.key
) t
group by
  t.id;

db<>fiddle

Thank you.  This works, but there is one caveat.  Is there a way to get the distinct value of dis?  Currently, there are duplicate values in the array.

Yes just add distinct to the inner jsonb_agg https://dbfiddle.uk/wVo3czRz
